# Doxygen and preformatted text in \todo

Tags: fonts, size, doxygen, fixed, todo

I am trying to use some preformated text in a \todo (because I need a a font with a fixed character size). So I have tried using `<pre></pre>`, `<tt></tt>`, `<code></code>` ...

I indeed get a fixed width font, but the problem is that if I put a `\todo` flag before that block, the \todo will be empty (it will ignore the block starting with `<pre>` `<tt>` or `<code>`)

Just to be clear :

- this todo works ; it displays a todo but the text is not preformatted

  ```
  @todo 
      1. First thing
      2. Second thing
  ```
- this is what I want to do, but it doesn't work ; the todo is empty

  ```
  @todo 
    <pre>
      1. First thing
      2. Second thing
    </pre>
  ```

**EDIT:** unfortunatly I can't upload images (not enough reputation)

Comment: Ok, if you place the @todo inside the <pre>, it sometimes works...  I have one file where it works, and when I copy/paste that working code in an other file, it doesn't work there (but the one one in the first file still works). Why is that?

Answer (score 2):

You may need to set the formatting on a line-by-line basis, instead of attempting to preformat the entire block. For example, you could specify:

```
* @todo
*     1. <tt>First thing</tt>
*     2. <tt>Second thing</tt>
```

Alternatively, if you have markdown support enabled, you should be able to specify:

```
* @todo
*     1. `First thing`
*     2. `Second thing`
```

With markdown support, it appears you can also use a fenced code block with `@todo`:

```
* @todo
* ~~~~
*     1. First thing
*     2. Second thing
* ~~~~
```